# Question on FunctionCompile

Tags: compile

So far, I have mixed feelings about the new compiler in *Mathematica* 12. Sometimes my results are a little bit faster, sometimes they are considerable slower than those obtained with the old compiler with the option `CompilationTarget->"C"`, and anyway it is much more typing. Now I met a simple example that I cannot get compiled.

With the old compiler in Mathematica the following works excellent:

```
fuc=Compile[{{lst, _Real, 1}}, Module[{s=0.},
   Do[s=s+z, {z, lst}]; s], CompilationTarget->"C"]
```

It returns a compiled function that is many hundreds times faster than the uncompiled function.

With the new compiler, I expected the following to work:

```
fun=FunctionCompile @  
  Function[Typed[lst,TypeSpecifier["PackedArray"]["Real64", 1]],
     Module[{s=0.}, Do[s=s+z, {z, lst}]; s]]
```

The result is a failure with a (for me) not very helpful message: `` Function Native`CreateIterator: no satisfiable candidate of the type {Integer64, PackedArray[Real64, 1:Integer64], Integer64}->Handle[MIteratorWork[v13092, v13092, v13092, Integer64]] was found in the alternative list <<324>> ``,  and tag `TypeError`.

I tried to improve my attempt by indicating the type of `s` and trying to indicate the type of `z`, without success.

I cannot imagine that the new compiler cannot compile the list form of `Do`. Any hint on what am I doing wrong and how should it be done is highly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a I guess it is an error in the internal type coercion. This is not overly surprising as this technology is pretty new. Best course of action would be to tell Wolfram Support about it. For the moment, `fun = FunctionCompile@Function[
   Typed[lst, TypeSpecifier["PackedArray"]["Real64", 1]],
   Module[{s = 0.},
    Do[s += lst[[i]], {i, 1, Length[lst]}];
    s
    ]
   ]` will do...

Comment: Still, `fuc` will beat `fun` by over an order of magnitude and `Total` will be another order of magnitude faster. Either I did not get how to use it or `FunctionCompile` is really no reason to be excited.

Comment: my experience regarding speed is the same. Check out, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195435/new-compiler-technology-in-v12

Answer (score 6):

The `CreateIterator` error suggests that only integer iterators are available. (I do not know whether they are the only ones or not; nor do I know whether to consider this a bug.  But it is worth reporting and see what WRI says.)

```
fun = FunctionCompile@
  Function[Typed[lst, TypeSpecifier["PackedArray"]["Real64", 1]], 
   Module[{s = 0.}, Do[s = s + lst[[z]], {z, Length@lst}]; s]]
```

[I just noticed @Henrik posted the same thing in a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197744/question-on-functioncompile/197745#comment512325_197744) while I was typing this up.]

Comment: Following your and @Henrik 's suggestion I reported both my observation that the new compiler cannot compile the list form of `Do`, and the speed difference between `fuc` and `fun` to WRI. They filed reports about both points, and remarked that `FunctionCompile` at the moment is experimental, so it might undergo substantial expansions and improvements in future versions of *Mathematica*.  The old `Compile[]` functionality will remain in the Wolfram Language for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Thank you, Fred, for reporting!