# How to use CompilerOptions?

Tags: compile, documentation, compiler

The refpage for `FunctionCompile`'s option `CompilerOptions` is empty of examples:

[image]

Does anyone know what keys and values can be used in the `Association` given to `CompilerOptions`?

EDIT:

> A support case with the identification `[CASE:4959188]` was created.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These are accepted as valid rules for `CompilerOptions -> { rules }`:

```
Options@Compile`CompileToCodeFunction
(*
{"AbortHandling" :> Compile`Utilities`$AbortHandling, 
 "AddRuntime" -> "SharedLibrary", "CacheExpr" -> False, 
 "DataLayout" -> Automatic, "Debug" -> False, 
 "EntryFunctionName" -> Automatic, "ErrorFunction" -> Null, 
 "ExceptionsModel" :> Compile`Utilities`$ExceptionsModel, 
 "ExecutionEngine" -> Automatic, "ExpressionInterface" -> Automatic, 
 "ExternalLibraries" -> {}, "ExtraPasses" -> {}, 
 "InlinePolicy" -> Automatic, "InvocationMode" -> "WolframEngine", 
 "LazyJIT" -> False, "LLVMOptimization" -> Automatic, 
 "LLVMOptions" -> Automatic, 
 "MacroEnvironment" :> Compile`$DefaultMacroEnvironment, 
 "MacroRecursionLimit" -> 5, "OptimizationLevel" -> 2, 
 "PassLogger" -> Automatic, "PassOptions" -> {}, 
 "ResetVariableID" -> True, "SaveIR" -> False, 
 "TargetArchitecture" -> Automatic, "TargetSystemID" -> Automatic, 
 "TargetTriple" -> Automatic, "TypeEnvironment" :> Automatic, 
 "TypeSystem" -> Automatic}
*)
```

However, `CompilerOptions -> Association[..]` throws an error:

> `FunctionCompile::compopts`: `CompilerOptions` setting `` <|AbortHandling :> Compile`Utilities`$AbortHandling|> `` is not a rule or a list of rules.

As for the values, the only official discussion of the compiler I'm aware of can be found in the presentations of Abdul Dakkak and Tom Wickham-Jones at [WTC 2019](https://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2019/presentations/#day4).  In Dakkak's notebook you can find `"InvocationMode" -> "Standalone"`, `"LLVMOptimization" -> 
 "ClangOptimization"[3]`, and `"AbortHandling" -> False`.  `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions@Compile`Driver`Private`getCodeGenOptions `` will yield a few sparse insights into the options.

The above was discovered with my usual trick:

```
FunctionCompile[Function[Typed[arg, "MachineInteger"], arg + 1], 
 CompilerOptions -> {Foo -> True}]
```

> `OptionValue::nodef`: Unknown option `Foo` for `` Compile`CompileToCodeFunction ``.